# Как с помощью Violentmonkey удалить элементы со страницы содержащих определенных текст

Tags: javascript

с js не дружу, но надо со страницы удалить элементы с попомщью Violentmonkey, есть примерно такая страница:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="content-area">

    <div class="shorts">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="desc">
                <p class="name">Это удалить</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="desc">
            <p class="name">Это оставить</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="desc">
        <p class="name">И это удалить</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как полностью удалить divы содержащие текст "Это удалить" и "И это удалить"? Гугление не помогло, то, что нашел не удалось применить в данном примере

Comment: Доброго дня, можете  попробовать этот скрипт:

document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach(el => {
  if(el.textContent.toLowerCase() === 'это удалить' || el.textContent.toLowerCase() === 'и это удалить' ) {
    el.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
  }
})

Но это только под ваш пример в зависимости от задачи нужно будет менять параметры

Comment: Спасибо,. все отлично работает, но изначально не заметил, что немного не так выглядят строки, она в таком виде:
<p class="name">это удалить<span class="add">100</span><span class="to">some</span></p>
как можно сделать, что бы при поиске игнорировались span с их содержимым?

Comment: Помогло, добавить  firstChild.text к el..textContent.toLowerCase(), в итоге как то так
el.firstChild.textContent.toLowerCase()

Comment: Ниже решение не подошло ?

Comment: он удалял только название, оставляя на месте родительские дивы, в моем случае это не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Возможное решение вашего вопроса.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach(el => {
    if (el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf('это удалить') >= 0 || el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf('и это удалить') >= 0) {
        for (item of el.childNodes) {
            if(item.nodeName === '#text') {
                item.textContent = '';
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
    <div class="content-area">
        <div class="shorts">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p class="name"><span class="add">100</span><span class="to">some</span>это удалить<span class="add">100</span><span class="to">some</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p class="name">Это оставить<span class="add">100</span><span class="to">some</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="desc">
                    <p class="name">И это удалить<span class="add">100</span><span class="to">some</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добавлю - при этом решение элемент не удаляется, а заменяет нужный текст на пустую строку